# Trigger prettyPhoto after PHP Post

Tags: php, mysql, post

Instead of going to another page after a successful INSERT, I'd like to trigger an instance of prettyPhoto to let the user know their email was successfully sent and to keep them from leaving the page, and for eye candy.

Right now I'm just using:

```
header("Location: http://website.com/thank_you.php");
```

I've tried to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.prettyPhoto.open('http://www.website.com/popup.htm?iframe=true&width=850&height=420');
                });
</script>
```

In thank_you.php after instantiating prettyPhoto, but it goes to the page first, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want this to go but here are my 2 cents. First of all, you are mixing up php and javascript. PHP is executed between two pages, and generates page html. So you can't act on the browser after a post was done unless you work with AJAX.

At that moment, AJAX will act as a communication between the server and the webpage and you won't change page per se. You will still query the browser and post something to it though.

So your first steo is to post your stuff with lets say JQuery and expect some JSON to come back to you. That JSON will tell you what to do, error output or success output. And that part will $.prettyPhoto.open() the page you want. So you'll stay on the same page error or success, and will display something on success.

Is that any help?

Comment: We'll see. I'll get with my guy and see if he can wrap his head around it. Else, we'll just stick with 'thank_you.php'  Thanks for the reply!